# How to change another object's animation from button click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, animation, button

I created this button prefab that is using the built-in Unity Button component, an image component with Raycast Target, and an Animator component that is playing a scaling animation when pressing the button. **The problem is occurring when clicking on the edge of the button graphic and holding the mouse button down.**

[image: UI Popup with the button that is being pressed. When the cursor presses the button on the edge it repeatedly plays the press animation very fast, switching between Pressed and Normal state.]

As the animation is scaling down the button size (as well as the image component with the Raycast Target) the mouse cursor is at some point no longer hovering over the button and the animation state is going back to normal. As the button scales back to normal size automatically (and while still holding the mouse button pressed) the button is getting pressed again - getting **stuck in a loop**.

How can I prevent that from happening? Do I need to modify the order of my components or maybe change something in the Animator?

[image: Button in Unity Inspector showing all components of the Button GameObject]

Comment: That sounds like only the visual should be scaled, not the actual button. I would split this into two objects: the actual button (that has no image or is transparent) and a child object that has the sprite,  the animator and has its raycast target set to false.

Comment: The reason I think so is: even if animation behaved as expected, if you had another object behind this button, it would get clicked as button shrinks - is that something that should happen?

Comment: Exactly, I would only like to scale the visual. The rectangle for the Raycast Target should always stay the same. However, if I add the Animator component to a child the animation does not play.

Comment: Are you setting the "controller" field of the Animator, when you are adding it to the child object? That's what makes it play after button click. Also, maybe check that the parent object is checked as raycast target  and child is not. You can verify that the button gets clicked properly by adding something (like a function that writes something to log) to the OnClick method in parent object.

Comment: Yes, the controller is set to the "Button" animator but it only seems to work when they are on the same GameObject.

Comment: Ok, I did check on a test project that the child object approach works, so there must be something missing - might be animation trigger in your case? This question (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1279966/trying-to-change-an-animation-with-a-ui-button.html) explains how to trigger an animation on another gameobject  - would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up what was said in the comments: you want the raycast target to stay the same size while animation plays. That's why you should probably split your Popup Button into two GameObjects: one will be the actual Button (that stays the same size) and the other will be animated, and then the question is mostly "how do I change another object's animation from button click".

To do that, you should have the Button component on the actual button, Animator component on the animated object, and in the Button's onClick list you should have the call to the animated objects' Animator Component -> SetTrigger with the name of the trigger you want as an argument. Also note that the animated object shouldn't be the raycast target, but the actual button should.

You can pick what happens when animation is triggerred again before it finishes (for example when button is clicked multiple times) by setting transition parameters in the animation controller. But in this case just separating the button from the animated image should do what you want, because the raycast target will now stay the same size and the animation won't get triggered multiple times anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try tomorrow and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add timer for check animation is running.
example :

```js
//your animation duration here:
private float animationduration = 0f;

bool isClickable = true;

//set your timer with default 0
private float timer = 0f;


private void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer > animationduration)
    {
        isClickable = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isClickable = false;
    }

    if (isClickable && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        clickFunction();
        timer = 0f;
    }

}

void clickFunction()
{
    //ur function in here

}
```

then click function can't use before the animation end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This would definitely be an option but I would prefer to find a solution that does not require code. Maybe there is a way to prevent the Raycast Target to not scale and remain static in size.